# In Angular 7, http-put request sends undefined data at back end (NodeJs)

Tags: node.js, angular7, http-put

I want to send some data (In JSON format) from the front end(Angular 7) to the back end (NodeJS) using Http.put request from the component file. In the main console, I am getting data as an undefined format. Below are my front end and back end codes respectively.

```
this.http.put('/api/home', {moo:"foo",goo:"loo"}).subscribe(ccc => {
    console.log("Status:" + ccc);
    this.b = ccc;
  })


router.put("/home", function (req, res) {
var aaa = req.body;
console.log(aaa);
res.send(cc)
});
```

In the back end, I am getting undefined from console.log(aaa). I want foo or loo.

Comment: in NodeJS, what happens when you do `console.log(req)` - you might want to check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51781432 also

Comment: I got a response like this: 
IncomingMessage {
  _readableState:
   ReadableState {
     objectMode: false,
     highWaterMark: 16384,
     buffer: BufferList { head: null, tail: null, length: 0 },
     length: 0,
     pipes: null,
     pipesCount: 0,
     flowing: null,
     ended: false,
     endEmitted: false,
     reading: false,
     sync: true,
     needReadable: false,
     emittedReadable: false,
     readableListening: false,
     resumeScheduled: false,
     paused: true,
     emitClose: true,
     destroyed: false,

Comment: @AkberIqbal Thanks for the suggested link. It helps me to fixed the issue.

Comment: What do you expect? Guessing from your code which might be incomplete, you are sending `cc` which you did neither declare nor set

Answer (score 0):

You have to use body parser first and then router.

```
app.use(bodyParser.json()); // support json encoded bodies
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false })); // support encoded bodies
app.use('/', router);
```